# Combine Bitflags

Tags: python, flags

I have several flags:

```
    None = 0
    HR = 1
    HD = 2,
    DT = 4,
    Fl = 8
..
```

etc

I want to create a function where I input a certain flag, lets say : 6.

Returned should be HDDT, since 2 | 4 = 6.
It can also happen that 3 or more flags are combined or just a single one.
e.g. : 7 = 1 | 2 | 4 => HRHDDT.

How can I return the concated string depending on the flag value?

In my case the enum has many more entries, which would make a simple if statement really uncomfortable, because I would have to cover hundreds of cases.

Is there any clever solution to this?

Comment: How are the flags stored?

Comment: I havent stored them yet - I know the values, but I am unsure whats the best way to integrate them. Directly in the if-statement, by creating some kind of enum..?

Comment: I 'd use a dictionary

Comment: The logical answer for an input of 0 would be the empty string, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the flags as a `dict` like so:

```
flags = {1:'HR', 2:'HD', 4:'DT', 8:'FL'}
```

and bit-wise `and` your number with the flags to retrieve the strings:

```
def get_flags(num):
    if num:
        return ''.join(flags[x] for x in flags if x & num)
    return None

>>> get_flags(6)
'HDDT'
```

Comment: The `return None` line is redundant, still +1

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for^^

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume we have a list somewhere with the powers of two:

```
flags = ['HR','HD','DT','Fl']
```

Then you can write the following function:

```
def power2():
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i
        i *= 2

def obtain_flag(val):
    if val:
        return ''.join([f for f,i in zip(flags,power2()) if i&val])
    else:
        return None
```

The `return None` is not necessary: it is the flag that maps to zero.

Or if you want a *list of the flags* (in that case the flags can be anything):

```
def obtain_flag(val):
    if val:
        return [f for f,i in zip(flags,power2()) if i&val]
```

This gives:

```
>>> obtain_flag(6)
'HDDT'
>>> obtain_flag(7)
'HRHDDT'
>>> obtain_flag(0) # returns None, but None is not printed
>>> obtain_flag(1)
'HR'
>>> obtain_flag(2)
'HD'
>>> obtain_flag(3)
'HRHD'
>>> obtain_flag(4)
'DT'
```

Comment: Why not use `enumerate` and `1<<n` to avoid needing the `power2` helper?