# pipe ("bitwise OR") in call to fcntl.lockf()

Tags: python, python-3.x, flock, fcntl, lockfile

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384493/4288043) contains the following line:

```
fcntl.lockf(fp, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

The pipe, is in Python a ["bitwise OR"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988665/pipe-character-in-python)

I have checked the Python docs for [fcntl.lockf(fd, cmd, len=0, start=0, whence=0)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf) and it says that cmd is one of:

> LOCK_UN – unlock
>
> LOCK_SH – acquire a shared lock
>
> LOCK_EX – acquire an exclusive lock

Have also been reading about those variables [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock)

Does anyone understand that line and what it does and if it would work with just one argument and no pipe symbol?

LOCK_NB is not even mentioned in the Python docs..

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44115670/combine-bitflags, and any other question on SO dealing with combining bit flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those names are *numeric constants*, each a power of 2. That means they are integers with a *single bit set*.

You can combine such numbers with `|` to produce an integer with multiple bits set, each bit representing a specific option:

```
>>> import fcntl
>>> fcntl.LOCK_SH  # bit 1 set
1
>>> fcntl.LOCK_EX  # bit 2 set
2
>>> fcntl.LOCK_NB  # bit 3 set
4
>>> fcntl.LOCK_UN  # bit 4 set
8
>>> fcntl.LOCK_SH | fcntl.LOCK_UN  # combine bits 1 and 4
9
>>> format(fcntl.LOCK_SH | fcntl.LOCK_UN, '04b')
'1001'
```

This is a very common way of passing setting configuration in system calls. `fctnl.lock()` is one such example, but there are many more where the same technique applies. The [`os.open()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) is another example, as are the [`re` module flags](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.A).

It is important to realise that these are *just integers*. Instead of setting the flags with `fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB` (setting bits 2 and 3), you could just pass in `6`:

```
fcntl.lockf(fp, 6)
```

and there would be no difference, as far as the `lockf()` function is concerned. The point of using named constants is that using these makes for *self-documenting code*.

Comment: Thanks had no idea. Checked in interpreter, `fcntl.LOCK_EX` is 2, `fcntl.LOCK_NB` is 4, `fcntl.LOCK_SH` is 1 and `(fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)` is 6. Could you describe what effect changing the things in that line will do? eg what if you had just `fcntl.LOCK_EX`  and left out the pipe and the second part?

Comment: @cardamom: first of all, teh `fcntl.lock()` call doesn't care how you create the value; you can pass in `4` or `6`. You need to read the documentation to see what will happen. Not using `LOCK_NB` means the call *blocks*, it won't return until the lock has been established. If you do set that flag, then the call raises an `OSError` exception if the lock can't be established.